# VS Unit Testing can't open database (sqlite3)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, c++11, sqlite

I am using Visual Studio with unit testing. Created a test project, whose directory sits inside the project I am testing.

I am trying to "unit test" a function which opens database files, and creates class objects based on the contents of the database.
The function itself actually works fine.

```
bool import_materials_from_db(const char *db_name){
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc = sqlite3_open_v2(db_name, &db, 2, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cout << "The database \"" << db_name << "\" was not found.\n";
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've cut the function down significantly, as this is the point where it fails.
RC indicates the error code SQLITE_CANTOPEN (14).
The other thing passed to the function is an std::vector<> holding my class. Don't believe this is particularly relevant.

I call the function like so:

```
import_materials_from_db("materials.db");
```

This works great within the main application, but as soon as I try it within my unit testing:

```
import_materials_from_db("test_database.db");
```

I have no luck.

Project Directory:

```
Advanced_Task_1\
```

Unit Testing Directory:

```
Advanced_Task_1\UnitTest1\
```

I have tried placing the database file within each directory just in case.
I have tried passing "..\test_database.db" etc. etc.
Lastly, it's worth mentioning, I am sure this is the correct file name and I am sure there is information inside the database to be read. Still no luck.

Any ideas on what exactly I am doing wrong? I tried the "look at the directory above" trick like I do in project settings "..\" but it didn't like that either.

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered the answer whilst writing the question.

I tried inserting the entire path just to be sure.

```
"C:\Users\Documents\VisualStudioProjects" etc.
```

This generated the error "incorrectly formed universal character name".

Universal characters? They're to do with backsla... Ohh....

So I tried my function like so (note the / instead of the \):

```
import_materials_from_db("../test_database.db");
```

And it worked!
Simply needed to reference the directory above the unit testing directory (..), and use a forward slash rather than a backslash.

Still wanted to post this question as I'm sure others will have similar problems in the future.

---

Even more interesting, this could have been achieved using a double backslash... \\ such as is necessary on this forum... Apparently windows treats them the same way (ish).

So, the answer is, rather than using:

```
"..\filename"
```

use this:

```
"..\\filename"
```

or this:

```
"../filename"
```